# How to create share button in android using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

My app has a share button that shares a link to the app on the play-store. I'm new to the intent method and keep getting this error:

[image]

**And this error**

[image]

Any input on how to correctly create a share button is greatly apreciated! Below is the code in ActivityMain and below that; the XML to the share button.

```
 private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
        // Inflate menu resource file.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

        // Return true to display menu
        return true;
    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        if (shareActionProvider != null) {
            shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }
```

**SHARE BUTTON XML**

```
  <item android:title="Communication">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/menu_share" />
            android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```

[image: EDIT Image of share via tab goal]

Comment: First Remove this lines `// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;` from `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Try Clean and ReBuild Project

Comment: Hey Chirag. I tried what you suggested and I got an error.  Cannot find symbol class ShareActionProvider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your menu item / button click call the following method.

```
private void shareAppLink(){
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    shareIntent.setData(Uri.parse("Link to app store"));
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I got an error when I pasted this method. Cannot resolve symbol uri.

Comment: @JavaHava you need to import Uri, add this to top of your class "import android.net.Uri;"

Comment: Thanks this works! The only thing I can't get to work  is the share via tab. See image in post. My apologies if I'm asking so many questions I'm brand new to android studio

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code:

```
     <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="@string/menu_share" />
    </menu>



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_share);

     item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_share){
                ShareApp();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    // Return true to display menu
    return true;
}


 private void ShareApp() {
        try {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
            String shareMessage = "\nLet me recommend you application\n\n";
            shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "\n\n";
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            DebugLog.e(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi try this code and let me know to work for you or not.

Comment: Hey Vasudev, thanks for taking the time out to help me, however this question has been answered and resolved by Ankush.

Comment: great it'z my pleasure to help you.:)